# My array of char arrays only saves the last inputted line

Tags: c++

My char array is only storing the last inputted string. For example if I input A, B, C, D, and E, it prints out E 5 times.

```
string line = " ";
char** arr = new char*[5];

int i = 0;

for(i = 0; i < 5; ++i)
    arr[i] = new char[10];



for(i = 0; i < 5; i++){
    getline(cin, line);
    arr[i] = (char*)line.c_str();
}

for(i = 0; i < 5; i++){
    cout<< arr[i] << endl;
}
```

Comment: There's a difference between copying a string and assigning a value to a pointer.

Answer (score 3):

The problem is you are assigning the address(not exactly) of `line` to `arr[i]` everytime, which never changes. It results in all entries of `arr` pointing to the same location.

You can do this..

```
for(i = 0; i < 5; i++){
    getline(cin, line);

    strncpy(arr[i], line.c_str(), 10);
}
```

Update: As mentioned in comments, you are actually assigning the address of internal representation of line.

Comment: It's worse than that, he's assigning the address of the internal representation of `line` and it _can change_ if `line` needs to reallocate for any reason (like that `getline()` call in the loop).

Comment: @Blastfurnace- Agree. I just wrote it in layman's terms, but I have updated my answer for that. Thanks! :)

Answer (score 0):

It's probably the case that `string::c_str()` returns a reference to the actual underlying array (i.e. the array returned by `c_str()` is modified if the string which returned it is modified).
The fact itself that `c_str()` returns a constant array should have warned you that you should not consider that array as under your control.

Another error you're making is `arr[i] = (char*)line.c_str();`. You previously allocated memory for arr[i], with `arr[i] = new char[10];`, but the second assignment erases the first one, resulting in a memory leak. I believe what you wanted to do is

```
strncpy(arr[i], line.c_str(), 10);
```

where `strncpy` is declared in the `<cstring>` header.

Answer (score 0):

'arr' is an array of pointers. You initialize these pointers with the addresses of five character arrays. But in your getline loop, you set each of the pointers to the address of your 'line' variable. The result is that they all point to the same string in memory (and you've just leaked five char arrays into the aether!).

Tip: try copying the contents of 'line' into each of your char arrays with a string copy function instead. Make sure you only copy a maximum of 10 characters!

Answer (score 0):

What you are experiencing shows that what is returned is the pointer to the internal array.

the docs for [string::c_str](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/c_str/) states for `C++98`

> A program shall not alter any of the characters in this sequence.

This does not clearly say it is the internal buffer but leaves it to the implementation advising to not alter it as it may point to the internal buffer.

Whereas for `C++11` it clearly states that this is the internal buffer

> The pointer returned points to the internal array currently used by the string object to store the characters that conform its value.
>
> Both string::data and string::c_str are synonyms and return the same value.

So what you need is to copy the content into your previously allocated array:

```
std::strcpy (arr[i], line.c_str());
```